# Need python files stored in Google Database to compile in Google Cloud Engine and return data to an IOS App

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

My Current Plan: 
I'm currently creating an IOS App that will access/change java/python files that are stored in the Google Cloud Storage. Once confirmed the App will talk with App Engine that will have a Compute Engine VM receive files and compile them. Once compiled have the result returned back to the IOS App

Is there any better or easier method to achieve this task? Should I use firebase or Google Cloud Functions? Would it be any help

Currently, I'm lost how to design and have requests sent between many platforms.

Comment: Why do you need an App Engine in between? Can't you essentially achieve the same thing using the Compute Engine instance?

Comment: Also I would suggest that you post  general product discussion related questions on Google Group since StackOverflow deals with technical questions.

Answer (score 0):

It would also depend on what type of data processing you are doing to the files in Cloud Storage. Ideally you would want to avoid as many "hops" between services as possible. You could do everything via Cloud Functions and listen on GCS [Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#event_types).  You can think of Cloud Functions as a sudo App Engine Backend to use for quick request handling.

> Use Cloud Functions to respond to events from Cloud Storage or Firebase Storage to process files immediately after upload

If you are already using Firebase, it would be better to stay within their ecosystem as much as possible. If you are doing bigger or more intensive data processing you might want to look at different options.

With more information and current pain points, we may be able to offer more insight.